# Split a list into a fixed number of random-sized sub-lists

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the quickest way to split a list into a specific number of chunks? I want the chunk size to be random but all the chunks to contain at least one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's the quickest way to do this, but I think something like that should work with fairly good distribution:

```scala
import scala.util.Random

def split[T](list: List[T], chunks: Int): List[List[T]] =
  if (chunks == 0) Nil
  else if (chunks == 1) List(list)
  else {
    val avg = list.size / chunks
    val rand = (1.0 + Random.nextGaussian / 3) * avg
    val index = (rand.toInt max 1) min (list.size - chunks)
    val (h, t) = list splitAt index
    h +: split(t, chunks - 1)
  }
```

Result:

```scala
split(1 to 100 toList, 10) 
List[List[Int]] = List(
  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
  List(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
  List(22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28),
  List(29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38),
  List(39, 40, 41, 42, 43),
  List(44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54),
  List(55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70),
  List(71, 72, 73, 74, 75),
  List(76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84),
  List(85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
)
```

EDIT: Here is more efficient, albeit less elegant tail recursive version. It builds resulting list in reverse, since calling splitAt with index near the end of the list would end up with O(n*n) complexity.

```scala
def split[T](list: List[T], chunks: Int): List[List[T]] = {
  @tailrec
  def split[T](list: List[T], chunks: Int, size: Int, result: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] =
    if (chunks == 0) result
    else if (chunks == 1) list +: result
    else {
      val avg = size / chunks
      val rand = (1.0 + Random.nextGaussian / 3) * avg
      val index = (rand.toInt max 1) min (size - chunks)
      val (h, t) = list splitAt index
      split(t, chunks - 1, size - index, h +: result)
    }
  split(list, chunks, list.size, Nil).reverse
}
```

Comment: adamwy How about making the function tail-recursive to avoid the stack overflow error caused in large inputs?